# Split only from the last dot if string has multiple dots

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have the following string:

```
"01.blaaa.html"
```

I would like to split only from the last dot onwards ,  my string may however also include `"01.html"` , so the output I'd like would be an array like so:

```
 "01.blaaa.html" // ['01.blaaa' , 'html'];
 "01.html"  // ["01" , "html"]
```

Of course if I use split('.') it will work for the 2nd scenario, but how do I resolve the first scenario ?

Comment: Use `/^(.*)\.([^.]*)$/` and 2 captured groups

Comment: You could split, count and join or split manually by getting the last index of a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()`

```js
var s = "01.blaaa.html";
var index = s.lastIndexOf(".");
var res = []
res.push(s.substring(0, index));
res.push(s.substring(++index));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: brillient thanks only `res.push(s.substring(index));` should be `res.push(s.substring(++index));` as in the secound array element i would like to exclude the dot

Answer (score 3):

You can also find the last index of that dot and `splice()` it to get the splited array:

```js
var str = '01.blaaa.html';
var index = str.lastIndexOf('.');
var res = []
if (index != -1) {
    res = [str.slice(0, index), str.slice(index+1)]
}
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks bhai voting you

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik glad to help